# How can I save and load a text in a ComboBox with Python?

Tags: python, combobox, serial-port, pyqt

Hello Im writing a program in python and pyqt4 to control a amplifier.The program connects with a serial port(pyserial module). Now I want to modify my version that it can be used on other platforms and computers. I have already loaded and add a list with all serial ports to a ComboBox. Because its exhausting to choose and connect the port every time Im starting the program, I want the ComboBox to save the last chosen Port and connect to it. I'm new in Python and have no idea.How can I save and load the last String chosen in a ComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can think of is doing some File I/O.

Say, you have a file index.txt . You would need to store the index, so, each time the combo box is activated, you open the file in read mode, read the number inside, close the file, change the integer to the current item's index, open the file in write mode, write the new integer to it and close the file again. This way you always have the latest chosen item's index stored in a file.

Then, at startup, you open the file again and read the string inside. You set the combobox's current index to that of this string using .setCurrentIndex(). This will automatically connect to a combo box's currentIndexChanged() signal.

Here an example program:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget()

        self.combo = QtGui.QComboBox(self)

        self.combo.addItem("Serial 1")
        self.combo.addItem("Serial 2")
        self.combo.addItem("Serial 3")
        self.combo.addItem("Serial 4")
        self.combo.addItem("Serial 5")

        self.combo.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.Show)

        f = open("index.txt","rt")
        index = f.read()
        f.close()

        self.combo.setCurrentIndex(int(index))

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        grid.addWidget(self.combo,0,0)

        centralwidget.setLayout(grid)

        self.setGeometry(300,300,280,170)

        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)

    def Show(self, item):

        print("Connected to: ",item)

        f = open("index.txt","rt")
        index = f.read()
        f.close()

        index = self.combo.currentIndex()

        f = open("index.txt","wt")
        f.write(str(index))
        f.close()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main= Main()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note: For this to work you need to create an index.txt file with a number in it, in the same directory as your program is.

Comment: Thank u . I solved it. I created a .txt-file with the last working ports and every time i start the program it scans over every line of the txt file and try to connect. with the try - except command